# Picker component doesn't show the selected value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to add a picker to my React Native application. However, it doesn't change to the selected value upon selection. Although the chosen values always show up when I test them in the console, the picker always shows the initial value. This is the parent component:

```
  const LineSizingScreen = props => {
  const lineSizingCalculations = [
    { label: "Choose the value you want", value: "" },
    { label: "Value A", value: "value-a" },
    { label: "Value B", value: "value-b" }
  ];
  return (
    <View>
      <CalcPicker
        initialValue={lineSizingCalculations[0]}
        availableCalcs={lineSizingCalculations}
      ></CalcPicker>
    </View>
  );
```

And This is the Picker component:

```
const CalcPicker = props => {
    const [pickerValue, setPickerValue] = useState(props.initialValue)
    const {availableCalcs} = props;

    return (
        <Picker
        selectedValue={pickerValue.label}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 350 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
            const chosenCalc = availableCalcs.filter( calc => calc.value === itemValue );
            setPickerValue(chosenCalc[0])
        }}
      >
          {availableCalcs.map((item, index) => {
              return(
                <Picker.Item key={index} label={item.label} value={item.value} />
              )
          })}

      </Picker>
    )
}
```

So it always happens that when I select Value A for example, the selected value doesn't change on the application, however when I console log pickerValue.label, I get value A as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does `value doesn't change on the application` mean? where do you expect new value has been updated? in `LineSizingScreen`?

Comment: I mean that when I select a picker item (e.g. value A), it should appear as the selected value on the screen. For example, the default value of the picker when the screen reloads is "Choose a value", and it has 2 options "Value A" and "Value B". So when I choose "Value A", the picker value should change to "Value A". The case is that doesn't happen, it remains as "Choose a value" although when I console log pickerValue.label which I put as selectedValue, it outputs "Value A" as expected.

Comment: may it be because you pass `selectedValue={pickerValue.label}` instead of `selectedValue={pickerValue.value}`?

Comment: to me your project works fine

Comment: The case is that I cannot find anything wrong, however it is not working as expected as the picker item value doesn't show up when selecting it.

Comment: after being selected entry is shown in dropdown to me. but you say, it does not work to you. are we looking at the same place? that link you provided 3 comments above?

Comment: It works now. It seems there was some caching before when I tested it. Thank you so much. You can write it as an answer so that I tick it as the right answer.